# custom paper size for labelprinter (Brother QL 570)

Tags: printing, cups

I have a new label printer (Brother QL 570) wich supports endless paper. My thought was, that I will be able to save paper by printing just as much paper as I need - wrong! 
The printer comes with paper sizes of 63mm x 100mm and 63mm x 29mm (and some others) but I need 63mm x 'felxible lenght' or something like 63mm x 40mm.

How can I change that? I will print from OpenOffice.

Thanks!

(Driver is CUPS, using Mint 17.1)

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to print a label with size 54mm x 90mm but I am not able to do it. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The CUPS drivers that come with the printer include a utility for adding custom paper sizes.

Open a terminal and type:

```
brpapertoollpr_ql570
```

And you will see the usage examples for adding and removing custom sizes:

```
 ===========================
 LPRng Paper Size Tool (v 0.1)  Copyright by 2005
 Usage: brpapertoollpr_xxxx -P QL-xxxx Printer Name [-n add a Lable Format Name (<=32 bytes) -w Media Width(unit:mm) -h Media Height(unit:mm)]/[-d delete Lable Format Name]
 For example:
 1. Add a new Label Format with "New Label Format" name and 29mm width and 70mm length:
        "brpapertoollpr_ql570 -P QL-570 -n New\ Label\ Format -w 29 -h 70" [enter]

 2. Remove the Label Format with "New Label Format" name:
        "brpapertoollpr_ql570 -P QL-570 -d New\ Label\ Format" [enter]

===========================
```

As an example, I did

```
brpapertoollpr_ql570 -P QL-570 -n long_label -w 62 -h 200
```

to set up a custom paper size called "long_label" which prints on 62mm continuous roll, a 200mm long label

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!

Comment: Have you found a way to alternate printing between two paper sizes? the _media=..._ argument seems ignored in my case.

Comment: the media= option does work.  You need to use it with the -o (option) argument in lpr.

e.g.

`lpr -o media=long_label`

Comment: See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248939/brother-ql-720nw-specifying-media-size-seems-ignored