# Brother QL-720NW specifying media size seems ignored

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, cups, lpr

The `-o media=...` is being ignored by the `lpr` command when printing on the Brother QL-720NW. I added custom paper sizes using:

```
sudo brpapertoollpr_ql720nw -P QL720NW -n "62mm x 25mm" -w 62 -h 25
```

which works when setting the new size from within CUPS *as default* for the printer. This modified the ppd file and yields (in CUPS):

```
Description:    QL720NW
Location:
Driver:         Brother QL-720NW CUPS v1.4 (grayscale)
Connection:     ipp://10.200.200.95/ipp/print
Defaults:       job-sheets=none, none media=om_br-l-0-b-3-e-01-a-5-f-9-a-9_61.91x24.96mm sides=one-sided
```

where the new medium has the weird name `om_br-l-0-b-3-e-01-a-5-f-9-a-9_61.91x24.96mm`.

However, assuming that I'm adding a couple extra custom paper sizes, there seems to be no way for me to specify one in the `lpr` command directly, such as:

```
lpr -P QL720NW -o media=om_br-l-0-b-3-e-01-a-5-f-9-a-9_61.91x30.96mm label_62x25.pdf
```

This will either print on the *default* size or make the power button of the QL-720NW blink red.

Any idea? This is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww Dude, most of your own answers are about openssl... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

This probably does not answer your question. Furthermore, you may not even own a Brother printer anymore... I found this post because printing to my QL-700 from Libreoffice made me see red blinking lights all over. Scream! Finally I figured out that setting *Only use paper size from printer settings* ON in the print dialog fixed my problems. And of course, I then set the size I wanted in the print dialog *Properties* Option.

However it is obvious to me red blinking lights mean your paper size is incorrect, some way or other. My guess is that lpr is ignoring your parameters for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but maybe it can help someone. The correct solution is:

```
sudo brpapertoollpr_ql720nw -P QL720NW -n "62mmx25mm" -w 62 -h 25
```

Do not leave space to the size